# AWS windows EC2 instance with Active Domain join, not allowing non admin users to login

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory

I have a windows EC2 instance. I have an Active Directory also.

I was able to successfully Domain join my EC2 instance with the Active Directory

I am able to login into my windows using RDP client and the ACtive Directory admin login and the domain

Now i have create new user in the Active Directory. I am not able to login using the new user.